# How to use Katex auto-renderer in Angular Project? (v7)

Tags: angular, angular7, katex

I have a requirement to **convert a paragraph that has markdowns and maths equations and display in browser**. Markdown is working frine. For maths equation, I tried [KaTex](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX) but could not figure out how to use it in my angular app. (v7)
Here is [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-katex?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

PS: i tried [ng-katex](https://github.com/garciparedes/ng-katex) and it works fine for simple equations. I **need auto rendering**, as my equations are present in between text. So auto renderer will automatically find and convert the equation. [katex-docs for auto rendering](https://katex.org/docs/autorender.html).

I am looking for a way to integrate maths rendering inside markdown pipe itsef.

Can someone please explain how to implement Katex??
Thanks in advance.